# Select values for a range of given indexes using Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying to take a range of elements from a list Where I have the List of indexes.

Note: I can do it easily using a foreach loop but I want it without using a foreach or for loop.

I tried using takeWhile method of linq as follows but they didnot work.

Example :

```
List<int> ListOfindexes ; // this has the list of indexses for which I need the values
List<int> mainList;
```

Itried something like this.

```
mainList.TakeWhile(value => ListofIndexses.Contains(value));//this is not working.
```

I have been breaking my head on this from 2 days. Help me out.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
var results = indexList.Select(index => mainList[index]);
```

It's not very clear from your question though...

Comment: Removed my answer since it will confuse OP and shame to me, Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I have a list of indexes(ListIndexes) and want to get all the values corresponding to those indexes from the mainList

Comment: @user1301449: Yes, and that's exactly what my code does... I used the variable name `indexList` instead of `ListIndexes` for the sake of consistency and naming convention, but I wouldn't have thought it would be that hard to understand.

Comment: As i want the values in the mainList that would be the reverse I think like mainList.Select(.......);

Comment: @user1301449: No, because it's selecting items from the main list. Look at the `Select` call carefully.

Comment: Oops Thankyou very much for your valuable time and help :)